# Is there a lower bound for $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ in terms of $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-factorization, arithmetic-functions

For integers $n\geq 1$ we denote the square-free kernel as $$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\text{ prime}}}p,$$ that is the product of distinct primes dividing an integer $n>1$ with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$ (the Wikipedia's article dedicated to this multiplicative function is [*Radical of an integer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer)).

Inspired by this [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812314), here is my own question:

> Is there a lower bound for $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ in terms of $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Sure, I know that $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is (weakly) multiplicative, and that $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$, but apart from these two pieces of information, I cannot seem to figure out how to obtain a lower bound, however trivial.

In particular, might it be possible to prove that
$$\operatorname{rad}(n) \geq \omega(n)$$
(where $\omega(n)$ is the number of *distinct* prime factors of $n$), or even
$$\operatorname{rad}(n) \geq \Omega(n)$$
(where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors of $n$ counting multiplicity)?

**Updated after the answers** The current known (somewhat trivial) lower bound is
$$\operatorname{rad}(n) > 2^{\omega(n)}.$$

Comment: $$\operatorname{rad} n = \prod_{p \mid n} p \geqslant \prod_{k = 1}^{\omega(n)} p_k \geqslant 2 \cdot \prod_{k = 2}^{\omega(n)} (2k-1) = 2\cdot (2\omega(n)-1)!! = \frac{(2\omega(n))!}{2^{\omega(n)-1}\omega(n)!}$$ for $n > 1$.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielFischer!  Does that lower bound result in a substantial improvement?

Comment: For numbers with a lot of different prime factors. If $\omega(n)$ is small, then not so much (though $2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 210$ is considerably larger than $2^4$, and already $2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 30$ vs. $2^3 = 8$ is something).

Comment: I think you should write out your last two comments explicitly as a complete answer, so that I may be able to accept it, @DanielFischer.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\operatorname{rad} n = \prod_{p \mid n} p \geqslant \prod_{k = 1}^{\omega(n)} p_k\,.$$

Using $p_k \geqslant k+1$ we obtain the bound $\operatorname{rad} n \geqslant (\omega(n)+1)!$. Using that all primes larger than $2$ are odd, we obtain

$$\operatorname{rad} n \geqslant 2\cdot \prod_{k = 2}^{\omega(n)} (2k-1) = 2\cdot (2\omega(n)-1)!! = \frac{(2\omega(n))!}{2^{\omega(n)-1}\omega(n)!}$$

for $n > 1$, and by Stirling's formula that lower bound is asymptotically equal (for $\omega(n) \to \infty$) to

$$\frac{1}{2^{\omega(n)-1}}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi 2\omega(n)}{2\pi\omega(n)}}\biggl(\frac{2\omega(n)}{e}\biggr)^{2\omega(n)}\biggl(\frac{e}{\omega(n)}\biggr)^{\omega(n)} = 2^{\omega(n) + \frac{3}{2}}\biggl(\frac{\omega(n)}{e}\biggr)^{\omega(n)}.$$

And using the prime number theorem we get an asymptotic lower bound via

$$\log \operatorname{rad} n \geqslant \sum_{k = 1}^{\omega(n)} \log p_k = \vartheta(p_{\omega(n)}) \sim p_{\omega(n)} \sim \omega(n)\log \omega(n)\,,$$

so anything growing sufficiently slower than $\omega(n)^{\omega(n)}$ can serve as a lower bound with a suitable factor to capture the cases where $\omega(n)$ is small. And anything growing sufficiently faster can't be a lower bound. [The weaselly "sufficiently" can be made more precise with more precise estimates for $\vartheta(x)$ and $p_n$.]

However, I doubt the practical usefulness of these bounds. If you know $\omega(n)$, then you typically know enough about $n$ to have much sharper estimates for $\operatorname{rad} n$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have $\omega(n)$ prime factors in rad$(n),$ each of which is at least $2$, so you have

$$\mbox{rad}(n) >2^{\omega(n)}. $$

Comment: We figured it out in exactly the same way, @B.Goddard!  See my answer below.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Blimey, how could I have missed it!

Since each prime $p$ in the factorization of $n$ is at least $2$, and since $n$ has $\omega(n)$ distinct prime factors, then a lower bound for $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is
$$2^{\omega(n)}.$$

Perhaps this (very) trivial lower bound could be improved?

**ADDED AFTER INITIAL ATTEMPT**

I am thinking this lower bound could be improved to
$$\bigg(n!\bigg)^{\omega(n)},$$
but I currently do not have a complete proof.  (*Edit June 9 2018*: As pointed out by [B. Goddard](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/362009) in the comments, this second inequality fails for $n=5$.)

Comment: I think that if you try your "improved" bound for a specific $n$ or two, you'll give it up.  Try $n=5$.

Comment: It needs some further tweaking, of course.  =)

I was thinking of using the trivial inequality $p_n \geq n$, where $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime in the canonical prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: But of course, the inequality does not work when $n$ itself is prime.  =(

Comment: The $k$th prime is approximately $k\ln k$.  So a lower bound might be built on $\prod_1^{\omega(n)} k\ln k$?

Comment: Not really.  As I have previously pointed out, the inequality fails when $n$ itself is prime.